# Android AChartEngine - Bar over Bar

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

Usually the Bars in a BarChart are aligned side by side. How can I have them to be on top of the previous one?
So I would think of creating series as I already have and adding them to a renderer, but telling the renderer to put the new series on top of the existing one, instead of putting it *beside* the existing one.
To calculate just the max value and display only one Series is not feasible, since I would have a lost of information though (I am using legends...).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of bar chart is called stacked bar chart. See an example of building such a chart with AChartEngine [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java).